# It is showing different css from development and build version how can i fix this

Tags: css, vue.js, electron

It is showing different css from development and build version how can i fix this.

This build devtools

[image]

This development dev tools

[image]

Comment: Have you declared css properties for `#footer` properties twice?

Comment: I only declared 1 time

Comment: do i have to declared it twice?

Comment: No I was just wondering because after building it seems to be declared twice, do you import the css twice Maybe?

Comment: i check all files  declared 1 time but devtools say 2 times

Comment: What happens if you change the id in your html and css, maybe a framework or smth has a style declared for `#footer`